# C# Class Library Exception Handling

Tags: c#, exception, class-library

Can I do this in a c# class library to handle exceptions that may occur during the execution of a class library code itself? I'm new in writing class libraries and exception handling within it. Please advice.

```
private void MethodName(String text)
    {
        try
        {
            ..............
            ..............
            ..............
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I've searched in google and stackoverflow, but did not find any article whether I'm allowed to handle exceptions in class libraries this way or if it is not a recommended way to do it. But it works. May be a dumb question, but I have this doubt.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want  to catch an exception just to throw it away again? Do something useful or don't catch it.

Comment: @Tim, there may be multiple errors, say nullpointer exception, outofrange exception, indexoutofrange exception etc, which I do not want to handle and throw each of them. So thought of catching a common exception and throwing it to the application calling the method.

Comment: If you code things that way, it will be difficult for a caller to do anything meaningful with any exceptions produced by the code you're calling.  Is that your intention?

Comment: And if you do decide to rethrow it, use just `throw;`. In the example you posted here, you completely _hide_ all the root causes of the failure. If you wish, you could create/throw a general `MyClassLibraryException` which has the root exception as its `InnerException`

Comment: @VinaySathyanarayana In that case just have `try {} catch (Exception ex) { LogMyException(ex); throw; }`

Comment: @supercat, I want to make sure that the caller knows that an exception occured and what the message is, but I do not want the caller to know the exact details of the exception.

Comment: @VinaySathyanarayana Are there particular reasons why you do not want the caller to know details? Security concerns? Shame/embarrassment?

Comment: @Chris - No security or any other reasons. If multiple errors occur within the class library, I've to include a throw statement at each location I can expect an exception. So to avoid this, can I do the above I asked.  Thanks for your advise.

Comment: Seriously you'll be making a nightmare of debugging for yourself if you proceed along this route. If you have some bug in your code, the stack trace that would help you pinpoint the error will just disappear in a puff of smoke as you throw a different exception. At the very least, you must include the original exception as an `InnerException`.

Comment: TimSchmelter and Matthew Watson - Before asking this question here, I referred a few articles in the internet, which says, send an error code if an error occurs or send 0 for success. Even in this case, the caller will not know the exact issue of the exception. How do we go about this? Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: As long as you preserve the original exception (as the `InnerException`) it's acceptible in *some* cases to catch and rethrow a different kind. But it's not usually as useful as you might hope. Suppose it was an `OutOfMemoryException`. What purpose could it possibly serve to rethrow a new exception with that as the inner exception?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, true, I understand what you said. Makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but in general you should only catch exceptions if you are going to do something with it - i.e. swallow it or add value to it (by transforming, wrapping or logging it).

Using your example method, you should throw an exception if `text` is null and your method expects a value. Other than that you should let exceptions bubble out for the caller to handle unless you are going to do something with it, or it is an expected exception that you intend to suppress.

You also shouldn't throw a new exception, instead just use the throw keyword to rethrow the current exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //do something

    throw;
}
```